# Powermockito: using thenReturn efficiently

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have mocked a method called `methodA()`.
I have a linked list called `linkedListA`.
Now,
i have a line of code to mock the return of `methodA`, as such
 `when(methodA()).thenReturn(linkedListA.get(0)).thenReturn(linkedListA.get(1)).thenReturn(linkedListA.get(2))` and so on

Now, is there a more efficient/cleaner way to write all the `thenReturns`, for instance, like in a loop? So, that I do not have to write tons of `thenReturns`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first improvement would be to use this:

```
when(methodA()).thenReturn(linkedListA.get(0), linkedListA.get(1), linkedListA.get(2)) and so on
```

Moreover, you could you the `thenAnswer` method to return a value:

```
final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
when(methodA()).thenAnswer(new Answer<YourType>() {

 @Override
 public YourType answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
     return linkedListA.get(i.getAndIncrement());
 }
});
```

Example:

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Blub.class)
public class Mockexample {

@Test
public void test() {
    Blub blub = PowerMockito.mock(Blub.class);
    final List<Integer> counter = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

    // blub.size() is final, only reason to use PowerMockito here
    when(blub.size()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return counter.get(i.getAndIncrement());
        }

    });
    System.out.println(blub.size());
    System.out.println(blub.size());
    System.out.println(blub.size());
}

}
```

The Blub clas:

```
public class Blub {
 public final int size() {
    return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: what are the imports for this? I am gettign answer cannot be resolved to a type?

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad sorry if I have not been clear, you need also the Mockito library in your classpath to make the example run.

Comment: i gave you full credit for this answer :D. May I ask another quick question about the same. Why does the following not work:  int k=-1;  when(blub.size()).thenReturn(counter.get(++k)) .   thanks!

Comment: Because the `++k` is only invoked one time in the ` when(blub.size()).thenReturn(counter.get(++k))` line and its value (1) is stored as return value for `blub.size()`. That is, if you call the `blub.size()` method later on not the `conter.get(++k)` method is invoked but the stored value (1) is returned. You can debug through the test code if you have too much spare time ;)